# why i can not create table in mysql with the name check

Tags: mysql

I wanted to create a table check but i do not why its not creating in the name check.I thought if i have made any errors in command so i changed to the name check1 and its working.May i know the reason for this?

```
CREATE TABLE check(
     name  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   password VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL

   );
CREATE TABLE check1(
     name  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   password VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL

   );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`check` is a reserved word.

You can check the whole list in [MySQL reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

**Edit**
To improve my answer (I may have to check it in the future), and coming from @cja answer's information, it is also possible to wrap the table name like this:

```
`check`
```

In this case, the name is not considered a reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

check is a reserved word in MySQL.

Try

```
CREATE TABLE `check` (
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);
```

However, it'll be easier for you if you choose another name.

Comment: @cja, I was mentioning your post in mine, I do not understand why you want that part to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

"CHECK" is one of the reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a set of reserved words. CHECK is one of them.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

check is the reserved word in mysql so u cant create table of name "check"

The CHECK constraint is used to limit the value range that can be placed in a column.